# WiFi not working on Ubuntu 16.04 on my Asus X550JX

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, broadcom

I can't see any available WiFi networks or anything that even resembles
WiFi settings. Output of lshw -C network

```
 lshw -C network
 WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
 *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Limited
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7900000-f7907fff
```

Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
    03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142
802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6605]
        Kernel modules: wl
    04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
```

RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5287] (rev 01)

Output of wget -N -t 5 -T 10
https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
  chmod +x wireless-info &&
  ./wireless-info

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24842726/

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 Already done.

Comment: Please edit the file `/etc/modules` to remove the entry `ath9k` Reboot and show us the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 sudo modprobe wl && dnesg|grep wl
Output: 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available

Comment: Secure Boot is enabled.

Comment: @Pilot6 Turns out that secure boot was actually on. Turning it off solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a confirmed bug on Ubuntu where wifi will fail to show or respond at all.  Generally this will occur only after your computer enters suspend and then resumes.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1574347

Are you still able to use wifi?
Do you have access to any wifi immediately after a reboot?